# Vim statusline shows ^[[2;2R^[[>41;330;0c^[]10;rgb:e5e5/e5e5/e5e5^G^[]11;rgb:0000/0000/0000^G after mapping Capslock to Esc

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap, vimrc

I added

```
au VimEnter * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
au VimLeave * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Caps_Lock'
```

to my `.vimrc` to map Capslock to Escape. Since then, vim *randomly* shows the following statusline upon startup:

```
^[[2;2R^[[>41;330;0c^[]10;rgb:e5e5/e5e5/e5e5^G^[]11;rgb:0000/0000/0000^G
```

Not every time, but only sometimes. I couldn't find out, what triggers it.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's hard: the escapes shown are not related to the keyboard.  If I encountered that in development, I'd build xterm with debug-traces and look for clues in the log.

Comment: Oh look!  "powerline" again.

Comment: It's generally inadvisable to remap `Esc`: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/why-does-this-esc-normal-mode-mapping-affect-startup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940801/mapping-esc-in-vimrc-causes-bizarre-arrow-behaviour